Markov chain, Probability
An insurance company starts with a principal amount of Ugx 4 million and registers daily claims  with probability of 0.4. Each day it registers a claim it loses Ugx 2 million otherwise it gains Ugx 2 million.

What is the probability that the company obtains a fortune of Ugx 8 million without getting ruin.
What is the probability that the company will get infinitely rich.
Suppose the company started  instead with Ugx 2 million, what would be the probability that it would go bankrupt?


What have you tried?

See the Gambler's Ruin
